# thumbnail is showing up full size

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

I'm making a basic html5/css web page.  For some reason, when I view the page in the browser, the thumbnail image is showing up as full size.  To create the thumbnail, I opened the large original in paint.  I resized it to a width of 150px and it calculated the height as 185px. Then I saved it with the thumb name.

Then, in my html code, I have the following:

```
<a href="../media/BookCover.jpg"><img src="../media/tinCanBookCover_thumb.jpg" height="185" width="150" alt="Tin Can Crafts Book" title="Tin Can Crafts Book" ></a>
```

However, when I view the page, I can tell I'm viewing a small image at a larger size because of the pixels showing.  Clicking the image is showing the full size image as expected.  Any ideas why it's not showing my thumbnail as thumbnail size?  I've done this elsewhere and it worked.  I know the page validates, except it's having trouble finding the stylesheet, but I do see the stylesheet changes when I view the page.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've provided which demonstrates the problem. Code in the question is necessary but not always sufficient. Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), such as a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Maybe your page is in cache and you are viewing your old version of your code?

Comment: How do I make sure it's loading the most recent version? I tried ctrl-r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  I had css to make img 100%.  I changed it so it was attached to a class instead of the generic image.